# add to the width of colums equally in css grid as browser window widens

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to make a layout with three columns with a gap between columns. The rules are:

1. column 1: between 250px and 290px
2. column 2: between 500px and 800px
3. column 3: between 250px and 290px
4. gap: between 20px and 48px

(If the browser window isn't wide enough I have a `@media` query to do something else, so don't worry about that.)

I want the spacing to increase equally as the browser window gets wider and then if the window is wider than all the widths then the gap should grow. That is:

At a browser width of 1040px:
250 20 500 20 250

At browser width of 1045px:
251 21 501 21 251

etc., but when a column hits its maximum then it stops growing, so at 1476px:
290 48 800 48 290

Then only the gap grows, so at 1478px:
290 49 800 49 290

Given the html:

```
  <div class="parent">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
```

I thought it would be as easy as something like:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1040px){
  .parent {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: minmax(250px, 290px) minmax(500px, 800px) minmax(250px, 290px);
    grid-gap: clamp(20px, 48px, 1000px)
  }
}
```

But that doesn't increase the spacing equally. I've been experimenting around with different options but I can't seem to understand what it is doing.

What am I missing?

*Edit*

I made some progress with:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 790px){
  .grid-parent {
    grid-template-areas:
      "nav sp1 main sp2";

    grid-template-columns:
      minmax(250px, min(290px,30%))
      minmax(20px, min(48px,10%))
      minmax(500px, min(800px,80%))
      minmax(20px, min(48px,10%));
  }
}
```

I made the column gap a separate column. Also, combining `min` and `minmax` is amazing. I'm trying to see if there is a way to do this without percents.

It would feel better to me if I didn't need a dummy column to control the gap, but at least this works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can accomplish what you want using [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). with justify-content: space-between.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .outer {
            max-width: 1380px;
            background-color: #777;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        .parent {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
        .c1 {
            width: 22%;
            background-color: #ccc;
            height: 40px;
            min-width: 250px;
            max-width: 290px;
        }
        .c2 {
            width: 40%;
            background-color: #f7f7f7;
            height: 40px;
            min-width: 500px;
            max-width: 800px;
        }
        .c3 {
            width: 22%;
            background-color: #ddd;
            height: 40px;
            min-width: 250px;
            max-width: 290px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="parent">
            <div class="c1">1</div>
            <div class="c2">2</div>
            <div class="c3">3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead sizing the columns, you can size the children and use `margin` to increase the visual gap once they are too small to fill the entire column.

Your 3 columns are average fractions of `1fr 2fr 1fr` (seen from the min width)

`gap` is supposed to be 20px at less , lets make it 20px anytime .

`margin` from a side, both or the other to finally spread the columns without *aftereffects* .

The idea to start from can be then alike

```css
* {
  /*101 reset */
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  gap: 20px;
}

div div {
  width: clamp(250px, 25vw, 290px);
  margin-inline-start: 0;
}

div div:nth-child(3) {
  margin-inline-start: auto;
}

div div:nth-child(2) {
  width: clamp(500px, 50vw, 800px);
  margin: auto;
}


/*let's see those empty divs */

.parent {
  counter-reset: divs;
}

.parent div:before {
  counter-increment: divs;
  content: counter(divs);
}

div div {
  padding: 1em;
  border: solid;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

For the mediaquerie, you may swap display from flex to grid to keep the gap functionnality and lay you things from a single column up to 3 :
possible example

```css
* {/*101 reset */
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 20px;
  /* set a max-width once columns are on their widest and visual gaps about 48px 
  290x2 + 800 + 48x2 = 1476 */
  max-width:1476px;
  margin:auto;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 790px) {
  .parent {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  }
  .parent div {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .parent div {
    width: clamp(250px, 25vw, 290px);
    margin: auto;
  }
  .parent div:nth-child(2) {
    width: clamp(500px, 50vw, 800px);
    margin: auto;
  }
  .parent div:nth-child(even) {
    margin: 0 0 0 auto;
  }
  .parent div:nth-child(odd) {
    margin: 0 ;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1040px) {
  .parent {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  }
  .parent div:nth-child(1) {
    margin-inline-start: 0;
  }
  .parent div:nth-child(3) {
    margin-inline-start: auto;
  }
}


/*let's see those empty divs */

.parent {
  counter-reset: divs;
}

.parent div:before {
  counter-increment: divs;
  content: counter(divs);
}

div div {
  padding: 1em;
  border: solid;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```